# How to query per month on ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a query in ASP.NET Core using PostgreSQL, my goal is to create a monthly sales report and and store it in the database.

My code now is to query all the data and I'm trying to change to query monthly data. How to get monthly data and save it to the database?

```
Dictionary<long, int> countList = new();

foreach (var item in Repository.repoSales.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.ID))
{
    var ID = item.ID;

    if (countList.ContainsKey(ID))
    {
        countList[ID]++;
    }
    else
    {
        countList[ID] = 1;
    }
}

foreach (var entry in countList)
{
    if (Repository.repoSales.Get(entry.Key).IsDeleted)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var Sales = Repository.repoSales.Get(entry.Key);

    Sales.monthly = entry.Value;
    Repository.repoSales.Update(project);

    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}: {entry.Value}");
}
```

Sample data:

Company

1. Apple
2. Samsung
3. Xiaomi

Sales

1. Apple - 02/2023
2. Samsung - 02/2023
3. Apple - 09/2022
4. Xiaomi - 12/2022

Now it retuns (total all sales):

1. 2 (Apple)
2. 1 (Samsung)
3. 1 (Xiamoi)

I want to make it monthly like:

```
02/2023 - 2
09/2022 - 1
12/2022 - 1
```

I'm running this code using a console app

Comment: Can you share `repoSales` details? You have filtered data by `ID` instead you should sort it by suitable fields which containing any datae value for instance saleData or created date.

Comment: You should strive to make your question as readable as possible. Leaving a day wad of leading whitespace in your code doesn't qualify. Extra horizontal scrolling is a pain at the best of times but I'm on a phone so it's even worse.

Comment: It's really unclear how the code you've provided relates to the description of your problem. You should read [ask] and then provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: Your first block of code can be written like this: `Dictionary<long, int> countList = Repository.repoSales.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.ID).GroupBy(x => x.ID).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());`.

Comment: There is not enough detail about your data model for us to know what "monthly data" means. Can you improve your question?

Comment: So, based on your edit, the above query shows you the general structure for counting based on some key. You just need to change the key from `ID` to `Month` and it'll work for you.

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming you have this data:

```
var data = new []
{
    new { ID = "Apple", Month = "02/2023" },
    new { ID = "Samsung", Month = "02/2023" },
    new { ID = "Apple", Month = "09/2022" },
    new { ID = "Xiaomi", Month = "12/2022" },
};
```

Then these are the queries to get a count by `ID` and a count by `Month`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> ids =
    data
        .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

Dictionary<string, int> monthly =
    data
        .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```